# Pull out and store individual content

Tags: php

I have been told that I can pull out individual content values from a posted `value` and then put them in a variable:

`$Product .= "${item_id}-${length}-${Category}-${each_item['quantity']},";`

The outcome of the variable would be something like: `women_boot-16 Inch-Virgin_boots-3` My product ID in this case is "women_boot". In my form, I execute `$product` into the value:

```
echo = '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $Product . '">';
```

In the page, I post to I have: `$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];` which would become `$product_id_string = $_POST['women_boot-16 Inch-Virgin_boots-3,'];`

---

I now want to pull each piece of content out from the post such that I can form them like this:

```
$id   =  women_boot
$length = 16 Inch
$type = Virgin_boots
$amount = 3
```

I have tried the following code, but it only works if I have one through three.  How can I make it works for all my values?

```
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {
$id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value);
$product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID
```

---

**UPDATE**
I need to pull out this content in to make it work:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT bb.Price FROM Product aa, Itemised_Product bb, Category cc 
    WHERE aa.Sef = :product_id
    bb.ItemID = :length
    AND 
    cc.CatID = :Category LIMIT 1");
    $stmt2->bindParam('product_id',$product_id);
    $stmt2->bindParam('length',$length); 
    $stmt2->bindParam('Category',$category);
```

Comment: Why don't you just put hidden fields for all the parts of it? You can have more!

Comment: Why comma ? surely it should be "-"

Comment: @MightyPork you mean for `custom`?

Comment: @user1281385 because it can be `men_coat-16 Inch-Virgin_boots-3,women_boot-16 Inch-Virgin_boots-1,` etc `comma` is a breaking point. It works for me

Comment: I meant, if you want to send several variables (parts of the `$Product`, you can just as well have multiple hidden fields. Then you don't need to parse it back to the pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product_id_string = "men_coat-16 Inch-Virgin_boots-3,women_boot-16 Inch-Virgin_boots-1,";
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)
$items = array();
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {
    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value);
    $items[$key]['item_id'] = $id_quantity_pair[0];
    $items[$key]['length'] = $id_quantity_pair[1];
    $items[$key]['category'] = $id_quantity_pair[2];
    $items[$key]['quantity'] = $id_quantity_pair[3];
}
print_r($items);
```

You can prepare your query as follows:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT bb.Price FROM Product aa, Itemised_Product bb, Category cc 
    WHERE aa.Sef = :product_id
    bb.ItemID = :length
    AND 
    cc.CatID = :Category LIMIT 1");
    $stmt2->bindParam('product_id',$item[0]['item_id']);
    $stmt2->bindParam('length',$item[0]['length']); 
    $stmt2->bindParam('Category',$item[0]['category']);
```

Comment: u miss one of my point... `$id   =  women_boot
$length = 16 Inch
$type = Virgin_boots
$amount = 3` is just an example. I need to to pull it out and put it in a variable. Just ignore everything after `=`

Comment: It is in a variable: `$item`. You can access whatever you want from it. $itme[0]['length'] is the the length of the first item.

Comment: PLEASE look at my question again I have update it to show my sql query after the `foreach`

Comment: I looked. So what's the problem? Instead of using a variable like `$product_id` you can use $item[0]['item_id']. That makes a lot more sense than making a different variable for all your data.

Comment: How sure of you with this? because this will go in my ipn script to cross check for price jacking.

Comment: You have to make sure the data that you are receiving hasn't been manipulated for price jacking, but that really has nothing to do with your original question or my answer. If you're worried about security, you might consider making a different question that focuses on that.

Comment: `$items = array();` is that needed?

Comment: It's not necessary as long as you know that there will be at least one array result. I always do that out of habit to prevent error messages.

Comment: @@pedeLeao I tested this out and it doesn't work. I think it something to do with ` $stmt2->bindParam('product_id',$item[0]['item_id']);
    $stmt2->bindParam('length',$item[0]['length']); 
    $stmt2->bindParam('Category',$item[0]['category']);` how can this be fix please

Comment: @llovechoc - Break the problem down into smaller parts and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: thanks alot... You don't know how much it means to me that you helped me. thanks again